# Cyclic Recurrence

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, recurrence

I was reading [this](http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+677) editorial for [Div2 Hard: PalindromePath](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=14100), where the recurrence formed initially is NOT CYCLIC

> An issue with the recurrence is that it is not cyclic. So we cannot just call f(0,1) in its current state.

and the editorialist tries to make it cyclic, but I'm not getting it.So,

Can anybody explain,

1. What are Cyclic and Non Cyclic Recurrences,
2. how do I know that a recurrence is cyclic or not and
3. How do I convert Non Cyclic Recurrence to Cyclic recurrence

Images of the editorial for those who can't access it :

[image: Editorial]

[image: Code]

[image: Code(continued)]

Comment: you should definitely add more explicit details about the problem and/or the editorial. I happen to have a topcoder account, but other readers might not

Comment: @cobarzan I guess one does not need a topcoder accounr to view the editorial/question...

Comment: I am pretty sure you are wrong (at least regarding the editorial). Even if you are right, you should still add more details, so that your question is self-contained.

Comment: I can access the problem, but not the tutorial...

Comment: @cobarzan Thanks. You were right.

Comment: @ead I've put the images of the editorial..

Comment: I have no idea what "cyclic recurrence" means, maybe you should ask this guy, he seems to be a nice fellow

Comment: I haven't seen the term "cyclic" used like this, but it seems to me that the problem with the original formulation is that it *is* cyclic: that is, solving the subproblem f(a, b) may require the solution to the original problem f(0, 1).  His or her solution successfully *breaks* the cycle, producing a chain of ever-smaller subproblems whose base cases can be trivially solved.  A top-down way to express the fixed formulation would be: Let f(i, j, k) be 1 if there exists a palindromic walk from i to j that uses exactly k edges, and 0 otherwise.  Now find the smallest k such that f(0, 1, k) = 1.